# What is the lock state after std::condition_variable::wait( ) exits

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> myLock( myMutex );
std:condition_variable queueWriterCondition;
queueWriterCondition.wait( myLock );
```

After

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> myLock( myMutex );
```

myMutex is locked. After calling wait() the lock is given up and the current thread is blocked.

Now my thread gets notified and wait() exists.

According to [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) "When unblocked, regardless of the reason, lock is **reacquired** and wait exits."

If I understood correctly unique_lock does not unlock automatically when going out of scope. In this case the lock would never be given up.

Based on my experience it however seems, that the mutex is NOT locked after wait() exits.

Who is wrong. Me or reference?

Comment: Who told you `unique_lock` does not unlock automatically?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/~unique_lock

Comment: After `wait()` returns you own the mutex. Then the destructor of `unique_lock` unlocks it.

Comment: That cannot possibly be proper code. The cond-var is *local* ?? As in, no one else can possible signal it since it didn't even *exist* until the line before the wait??

Comment: That is correct. That was just for keeping the sample compact.

Comment: Super guys. Thanks all. Don't know where I picked up that unique_lock does not unlock on dereference.